# Looking for a free, usable alternative for remastersys

Tags: gratis, linux, backup, iso

[Remastersys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys) was an old backup program that converted a running Ubuntu or Debian system into an installer disk with the same packages as the 'master' installed, or into a live backup of the environment you were working on. It was *dead* simple (basically entirely automated as long as it was a supported system with enough space), and very useful for remastering your own disks. And the person who developed it had some [clashes of personality](https://web.archive.org/web/20130908040033/http://www.remastersys.com/) with persons unknown, and, unfortunately, stopped developing it. Black Lab Linux's [System Imager](http://system-imaging.blogspot.sg/) is a fork of this, but let's just say the selling price, and what I'm willing to pay don't match.

So, this is what I need:

- I need to be able to back up a *running* Linux system with all the packages on it
- I need to generate an ISO from this which I can then mount on live USB
- It needs to be relatively simple - I don't want to jump through a bunch of hoops to get this to work
- GUI preferred, though if it's curses-based and will run me through dialogues to back up a CLI-only system, it's super-cool
- Works on Ubuntu and Debian at least, though if it works on Fedora and RHEL, I'd be overjoyed

Options I'd like to have:

- Pick between backup mode - with my /home copied over to the live CD too or to generate a 'fresh' system for install with my packages
- supports Btrfs filesystems

Comment: Does https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=%20remastersys  help?

Comment: In the near decade since I asked this question I have seen at least one remastersys fork wither on the vine and switched my Linux builds to pure CLI systems that are nearly reproducible from my notes. I kinda stopped needing remastersys at some point 

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/190133/what-are-the-alternatives-for-remastersys and https://askubuntu.com/questions/452022/remastersys-alternative

See [**Pinguy Builder**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/):

> The script creates a livecd of the installed system and works with *buntu. 
>   You can either make a distributable livecd or a backup of your system.
>   Version 3.* works with *buntu systems 14.04 
>   (May also work with 14.10. If not use version 4.*)
>
> Version 4.* works with *buntu systems 15.04+ 
>   (15.10 Beta1 is missing xresprobe)
>
> xresprobe can be downloaded from here: 
>   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xresprobe
>
> Once xresprobe is installed in 15.10 Pinguy Builder will work/install.

Answer (score 1):

The project lives on [here](https://github.com/nerun/remastersys).

Images >4GB [now supported](https://github.com/nerun/remastersys/issues/11).

All we need now are ports to other Linux versions for portability e.g from AWS:

```
sudo apt install remastersys*.deb

sudo apt install xorriso

man remastersys

sudo remastersys backup
```

```
  ___ ___ __  __   _   ___ _____ ___ ___  _____   _____
  | _ \ __|  \/  | /_\ / __|_   _| __| _ \/ __\ \ / / __|
  |   / _|| |\/| |/ _ \\__ \ | | | _||   /\__ \\ V /\__ \
  |_|_\___|_|  |_/_/ \_\___/ |_| |___|_|_\|___/ |_| |___/
  Version 4.9-1

BACKUP MODE SELECTED

Checking if the /home/remastersys folder has already been created.

Copying /var and /etc to temporary area and deleting extra files.

Setting up Live CD options for mode backup.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-25-cloud-amd64
live-boot: core filesystems devices utils memdisk udev blockdev dns.

Copying your kernel and initrd to the Live CD.

Creating filesystem.squashfs. It will take a while, so be patient...

Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/remastersys/ISOTMP/live/filesystem.squashfs, block size 1048576.
[================================================================================\] 29001/29001 100%

...
Creating remastersys-livecd.iso in /home/remastersys using grub-mkrescue.

Creating remastersys-livecd.iso.md5 in /home/remastersys.

/home/remastersys/remastersys-livecd.iso is ready to be burned or tested in a virtual machine.

Check the size and if it is larger than 4GB, the USB key must be formatted in exFAT:
365M /home/remastersys/remastersys-livecd.iso

It is recommended to run "sudo remastersys clean" once you have burned and tested the image remastersys-livecd.iso.
```

Comment: [nerun](https://github.com/nerun/remastersys)'s remastersys has been archived by the author on 2024-01-07. Just before the license was changed (GPLv2 to GPLv3), which is odd to me.